# Docker desktop install in container fails on /etc/hosts .. what do to?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to install docker engine inside a container.

```
wget https://desktop.docker.com/linux/main/amd64/docker-desktop-4.16.2-amd64.deb
apt-get install -y ./docker-desktop-4.16.2-amd64.deb
```

Everything goes fine until in the post install phase, it tries to update /ect/hosts files for the kubernetes. Here it fails:

/var/lib/dpkg/info/docker-desktop.postinst: line 42: /etc/hosts: Read-only file system

This is expected behaviour for docker build in that it does not allow to modify /etc/hosts of the container.

Is there a way to solve this? Install docker desktop without doing this step? Or any other way?

Comment: You're installing the heavyweight closed-source Docker Desktop tool, not the core Docker engine.  Do you need a different package name?  You can't run Docker Desktop in a container since it wants to launch a Linux VM.  (It's merely hard to run the Docker engine in a container, and not usually recommended, but it's at least possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this issue by adding this parameter in build

--add-host kubernetes.docker.internal:127.0.0.1

Example:
docker build --add-host kubernetes.docker.internal:127.0.0.1 -t stsjava2 .